# Using restkit to seed a preloaded database

Tags: ios, restkit

I am attempting to create an object store with a seed database of about 500 MB. Here is how I do it:

```
self.restObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"DB.sqlite"
                                                                            usingSeedDatabaseName:@"SEED-DB.sqlite"
                                                                                  managedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel
                                                                                                     delegate:nil];
```

However whenever I do an adhoc deploy the application crashes with the " failed to launch in time" error. (Note: No problems occur when I try this with XCode)

Is there a way to improve performance of this operation? What can I do to avoid this error? Is it a too big seed database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty huge seed database! I would suggest first trying out with a smaller one to make sure it's not caused by it's huge size. The RKTwitterCoreData exemple has a good exemple on how to seed an initial store:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Examples/RKTwitterCoreData/Classes/RKTwitterAppDelegate.m

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it solved the problem. I was just wondering if there was another way around the issue.

Comment: By around the issue, what do you mean? About the database size?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to keep the seed database at that size. But I have reached a half-way term about the problem. I now have a smaller seed database and if more data is requires it is "updated" OTA using RestKit's mappings.

Answer (score 0):

The "failed to launch in time" error is an error you get if you do not return from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in a reasonable amount of time.  In general to avoid this you should do as much as you can off the main thread.  This particular case is no different, you should perform the object store creation in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue when my seed database was around 60Mb. I have splinted the Database